# Сравнить результат Speech To Text с заданной фразой

Tags: android, tts, распознавание-речи

Пытаюсь сравнить слово полученное с помощью Speech To Text, с заданным словом в условии. Идея в следующем: если слово совпадает с заданным, то оно появляется, если нет, то не появляется. После написания мною кода с добавлением условия, слово не отображается, если условие убираю появляется.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button recognizeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    recognizeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "You may speak!");
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.ENGLISH);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<String> results;
        results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            TextView speechText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        //if (results.equals("car")) {
            speechText.setText(results.toString());
     //   }
    }
}
```

Подразумеваю, что ошибка в условии if, надо results дать знать что он toString до условия, а не в нем, пробовал менять, но что-то не получается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этой строчке

```
results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
```

вы получаете массив, потом

```
speechText.setText(results.toString());
```

вы приводите массив к строке. Отсюда и скобочки. Пройдите по всем элементам массива

```
results[i].toString()
```

где i - это счетчик от 0 до results.size()

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<String> results;
        results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        TextView speechText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String str="";
        for(int i=0;i<results.size();i++){
           str+=results.get(i);
        }
        if (str.equals("car")) {
            speechText.setText(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю! Только в цикле for попросил заменить str+=results[i]; на str+= results.get(i);

Comment: Да, действительно поспешил)